# Formula to Show How Far Away a Number is From The Uppermost Value in a Range

Tags: excel, range, formula

I thoroughly enjoy an Excel challenge, but have found myself stumped on this one and through sheer curiosity thought I'd put it out there for others to attempt.

I have been challenged to think of a formula which shows how close three different values are from being classified as part of the next threshold in the sample data below.

```
Values

12458 (Okay)
28451 (Good)
54851 (Excellent)

Threshold

0        10000    Poor
10000    20000    Okay
20000    35000    Good
35000    50000    Great
50000             Excellent
```

What I need to do is think of a formula which will tell me how far away (if applicable) one particular value is from the next threshold.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar threshold challenge]

The formula in cell E2 and copied down is (to get the classification):

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$6,2)
```

The formula in cell F2 and copied down is (to get the threshold distance):

```
=IF(D2>=MAX($A$2:$A$6),"Already maxed",LOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$A$6,$A$3:$A$7)-D2)
```

Comment: Perfect; I already know how to do the first `VLOOKUP` - I just wasn't certain how to go about the distance-to-next-threshold.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LOOKUP` function, e.g. if your value is in A3 and your table is in A9:C13 then fill in B13 with a "+" and use this formula

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(A3,A$9:B$13)-A3,"No higher category")`

You'll need to decide what to do with values exactly on the boundary - is 10,000 Poor or Okay? (My formula puts it in the "Okay" category)